# De-serializing an array of dictionary<string,object>

Tags: c#, .net, json, .net-4.0, dictionary

I'm getting a JSON object with an string like:

```
"rec":[
    {"f":["T","R"],"u":316,"fName":"test","lName":"test2"},
    {"f":["C","R"],"u":990,"fName":"beth","lName":"tin"}
],
```

I'm trying to de-serialize it using the DataContractSerializer and by having a DataMember contract into a member of type `public Dictionary<string,object> [] rec;` But i get an error like:

> Object of type 'System.Object' cannot
>   be converted to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]'.

Can someone explain to me how I should go about deserializing this string ?

Answer (score 1):

why not use [json.net](http://json.codeplex.com/)?

deserialization from their docu:

```
string json = @"{""key1"":""value1"",""key2"":""value2""}";

Dictionary<string, string> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);

Console.WriteLine(values.Count);
// 2

Console.WriteLine(values["key1"]);
// value1
```

which could be enhanced on classes with contain certain `[Json...]`-attributes ... If you are working with `DataMember`-attributes, you can go straight for json.net, as they support the usage of `DataMember` and alikes ...

serialization should work too - just have tried lists and alike-stuff yet which worked more than fine for me!

Comment: I solved it by actually creating an inner class called 'rec' within my main class and giving it members called f,u,fName,lName and that worked. Probably I understood it wrongly to start with, it was not a dictionary but a JSON within a JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the JavaScriptSerializer:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var result = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>("{" + data + "}")
```

Comment: [Here’s the link to `JavaScriptSerializer` on MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

Comment: Hi, this is not just an indiviual string but a part of a bigger JSON object. The rest of it get deserialized using ReadObject but I get an exception when it is trying to deserialize this. I'm using the DataContractSerializer throughout the project so not sure if changing to JavaScriptSerizlizer is a viable option for me. Thanks